# Mocha passing test when i expect throw, but muy function is not throwing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I have a function that I expect to throw an error, but if it doesn't throw it mocha passes the test.

```
async function throwError() {
   throw new Error("foo");
}
async function notThrowError() {
   
}
```

Test:

```
describe("bar", function(){
  it("bar-2", async function() {
     await expect(throwError()).throw //passes the test
})
}

describe("bar", function(){
  it("bar-2", async function() {
     await expect(notThrowError()).throw //passes the test, but no error has been thrown 
})
}
```

Comment: Shouldn’t that be [`.throw()`](//www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#throwerrorlike-errmsgmatcher-msg)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I assert throw when `new constructor()` with mocha and chai](/q/36640291/4642212).

Comment: @SebastianSimon That question doesn't help me, maybe it's because of my asynchronous functions.

Comment: `expect(`…`).throw` is a function. `await`ing a function doesn’t really do anything. You need to _call_ the function. Did you try that?

Comment: @SebastianSimon what do you mean by calling the function, `notThrowError()` is not correct?

Comment: I mean what I said in my first comment: `.throw()` instead of `.throw`. However, that’s also a good point. `expect` expects a function. `throwError()` is nothing, and `notThrowError()` is `undefined`, none of which are functions. These lines should be `await expect(throwError).throw()` and `await expect(notThrowError).throw()`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon And if the functions have params?

Comment: _“And if the functions have params?”_ — Then make a function that doesn’t: `() => someFunction(having, params)`.

Comment: Your function _doesn't_ throw an error - it's async, it returns a promise that rejects. Use e.g. https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should use `chai as promised`

```
const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
chai.should();

describe("bar", function(){
   it("bar-2", async function() {
      return notThrowError().should.eventually.rejected; //do not pass the test if not throw an error
   })
}
```